# ¿Por qué no retorna la suma de los números?

Tags: c#, parsear

Intento realizar una función que me retorne la suma de los números que hay en una cadena, un ejemplo puede ser `"123" = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6`

```
public int Funcion(string numeros)
{
    int sumas = int.Parse(numeros);
       int suma = 0;
       while (sumas > 9)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++)
           {
               suma += numeros[i];
           }
           numeros = suma.ToString();
       }
       return int.Parse(numeros); 
}
```

Comment: Y cuál es la pregunta? Qué pasa con el código que nos compartes? Qué error te sale? Qué pasa cuando lo usas?

Comment: No hace falta que en un metodo de devuelves un int, esa suma la transforme a string para luego una linea abajo volver a convertirlo en int.

Comment: [No deberías forzar una etiqueta en el título](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2464/qu%c3%a9-significa-no-deber%c3%adas-forzar-una-etiqueta-en-el-t%c3%adtulo)

Answer (score 2):

Esta es una opción:

```
    public int Total(string numeros)
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++)
        {
            total += int.Parse(numeros.Substring(i, 1));
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola tu function esta mal diseñada en base a lo que quieres lograr.
te explico linea por linea.

`int sumas = int.Parse(numeros);`

Aqui como ves si yo le paso a `int.Parse` una cadena como esta `"1234"`
me va a retornar `1234` de tipo entero.
Pero si le paso `"1"` tu variable `sumas` sera siempre menor que `9` por lo tanto entraras en un bucle infinito del cual tu funcion jamas saldrá
me refiero aqui. 
`while (sumas > 9)`
Por lo tanto esta linea esta mal.
Para lograr lo que quieres la funcion quedaria asi

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = Funcion("123");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public static int Funcion(string numeros)
    {
       int suma = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++)
       {
         int n = numeros[i] - '0'; // convert char to int;
         suma += n;
       }

       return suma; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si sumas los caracteres, tendrás un resultado inesperado. Tal y como estás programando tu suma de dígitos, el resultado debería ser 150:

El carácter `'1'` tiene valor `49`, el carácter `'2'` tiene valor `50`, El carácter `'3'` tiene valor `51`.

> 49 + 50 + 51 = 150.

Tienes que convertir el carácter a su valor  numérico y después sumar:

```
static double Suma(String numero)
{
    var valor = numero.ToCharArray().Select(v => Char.GetNumericValue(v)).Sum();
    return valor < 10 ? valor : Suma(valor.ToString());
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9LS8RAEITPmV/R7GlyMLg@wewqsgcvKkJED@Khd7aJA/PAngcssr89JtlBPFb3V9XVKpwozzQMKWjXQ7cPkWwr/qvmUbvvVghlMAR4Yd8zWvgRVYgYtYKdT1tD0CWLsos8GV2yxL4W1UhVGRkyGs@wLovm1W@@kO@ZcS/rpiNDKsoM61uY5s0DxecJ1OoNTSKZ6xFKVtbtGMcUE7uSuILlKdwVcXPsMIvxxLGLrCfXQfzVzV7v4Am1k2EGPj4BuQ@l7Ma74A0176wjjY@TnDMX11eXF@dny0VJOwzDLw)</kbd>.