# Como puedo hacer la suma de los dígitos de un numero

Tags: c#

Quiero que el programa sume los dígitos de un numero que se ingresa ejemplo:

123 | 1+2+3=6

si el numero es de un solo dígito solo lo imprime.

esto es lo que he intentado:

```cs
int suma = int.Parse(numeros);  
int acum = 0;  
  do  {  acum =0;  
         while (suma >0) 
         { 
          var cifra = suma % 10; 
          acum += cifra;
```

Comment: Agrega el código como texto por favor , en tus preguntas, revisa [ask]m saludos.

Comment: Buenas, lo priemro te aconsejo que subas codigo escrito y no imagenes del mismo, asi te podran ayudar mejor. Una forma sencilla seria el numero que escribe el usuario por pantalla (input), que en principio seria un String en vez de Integer, podrias dividirlo uno por uno y pasarlo a un array, luego ese array lo recorres y vas parsando a Integer los Strings divididos y justo despues vas sumando ese numero a una var aux que tengas por ahi (entu caso parece ser la variable acum ).

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Por que no me retorna la suma de los números?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361240/por-que-no-me-retorna-la-suma-de-los-n%c3%bameros)

Answer (score 3):

Deberías poner el código en lugar de un imagen.

Creo que lo que quieres hacer es algo así:

```
int n = 123; //int.Parse(numeros);
int sum = 0;
while (n != 0) {
    sum += n % 10;
    n /= 10;
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Answer (score 3):

En esta caso puedes convertir la cadena primeramente a un array de caracteres e interar sobre este array

```
   String numeros = "123";
   char[] arrayNumeros = numeros.ToCharArray();
```

Al iterar conviertes a entero cada elemento dentro del array y realizas la suma de los números, ejemplo:

```
        String numeros = "123";
        char[] arrayNumeros = numeros.ToCharArray();

        int suma = 0;
        foreach (char numero in  arrayNumeros)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("numero:  " + numero);
            suma += int.Parse(numero.ToString());
        }

          Console.WriteLine("suma:  " + suma);
```

salida:

```
suma:  6
```